# Cannot convert value of type [String : String?] to expected argument type [String : String]

Tags: swift

I am trying to save data to my plist file which contains definition of array of strings. My plist -[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnwcP.png)

My code for writing the data to my plist is --

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask,true) as NSArray

let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSString

let path= documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("authors.plist")

let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager( )

var plistArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as! [Dictionary<String , String>]

var addItem: Dictionary = ["link": linkBook.text , "Cover": cover.text , "title" : titlePage.text , "year" : year.text , "isbn" : isbn.text]

plistArray.append(addItem)
// I am getting the error here 

(plistArray as NSArray).writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `linkBook`, `cover`, `titlePage`, `year` and `isbn` all represent text fields in your UI?  The `text` property of one or more of whatever those things has a type of Optional String (`String?`).  The `plistArray` variable is of type `[String, String]` – neither the keys nor the values can be nil.

Fundamentally you need to answer the question of what to do if the `text` property of one of the things mentioned above is `nil`.  It could be the case that they are never empty in which case you could add exclamation points to them `linkBook.text!` and `cover.text!` etc.

If you do that, however, and any of them ever is nil, that will lead to a crash.

I suspect instead that what you want to do is use the `??` operator.  Set up your dictionary as:

```
var addItem: Dictionary = ["link": linkBook.text ?? "", 
  "Cover": cover.text ?? "", 
  "title" : titlePage.text ?? "", 
  "year" : year.text ?? "", 
  "isbn" : isbn.text ?? ""]
```

That way if any of the ever is `nil` then you will get the empty string in your plist.

Answer (score 0):

The textfield.text is an optional. So you should unwrap it first.

`var addItem: Dictionary = ["link": linkBook.text! , "Cover": cover.text! , "title" : titlePage.text! , "year" : year.text! , "isbn" : isbn.text!]`

Comment: Note that with this change, if any of the `xxx.text` properties is ever nil, your application will crash.

Comment: I understand it will crash but we can  take appropriate measures to avoid crashes. Just create the dictionary only if the textfield is not empty.